# JQuery JSON ARRAY Issue

Tags: jquery, json

I am having issues parsing the json returned from a serlvet.

in my jsp page I used ajax to post to a servlet and it will return a json object.

Here's the Json format:

```
"data":[{"unit":"'A'","value":"40"},{"unit":"'B'","value":"16"}]"
```

object data contains multiple arrays.

In JQuery, I want an array that contains arrays from the json.

```
var dataArray = [];
```

I need dataArray to be: dataArray => [['A', 40], ['B', 16]]

**SORRY, this is a snippet from my code.
Here's the JSON. I have confirmed that it is a valid JSON.
{"data":[{"unit":"'A'","value":"40"},{"unit":"'B'","value":"16"}]}**

Comment: how you parsing your json ?show the code

Answer (score 0):

If this:

```
"data":[{"unit":"'A'","value":"40"},{"unit":"'B'","value":"16"}]"
```

is what your server is returning, it won't validate as a JSON object. It needs to be surrounded in braces, and have the trailing `"` removed:

```
{"data":[{"unit":"'A'","value":"40"},{"unit":"'B'","value":"16"}]}
```

You can use
http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your object to make sure that the server is returning valid JSON.

Once this is fixed, the following javascript should work for you:

```
$.getJSON("http://server.com/whatever.json", function(data) {
    var dataArray = data.data; 
    // dataArray processing goes here
});
```

Comment: OK, I used var dataArray = data.data; Now my dataArray is [object Object],[object Object].  It is still not in the format that I needed dataArray needs to be [["A",40],["B",16]]

Comment: If it did not work, perhaps you can show more code, please? Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: "GetJson",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "JSON",
        error:function(){
            alert("error occured!!!");
        },
        success: function(data) {

  var dataArray = data.data;
  alert(dataArray);
 }
});

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code with formatting, and let us know what errors you are getting (if any). In particular, that url looks suspicious - it doesn't contain the protocol or server.

Comment: ok, but how can the url looks suspicious? It's a servlet that I created in my Eclipse workbend within the same project.  A servlet name is GetJson (plain and simple) for this tutor I am doing. This is not in production or anything, just a simple tutor I am following to understand JQUERY and JSON.